# Null Data Item From Wearable.DataApi.getDataItem

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api, android-googleapiclient

My wearable has an `Activity` that `implements DataApi.DataListener`, this `Activity` sends a message in `onConnected()` to the handheld to update the requested data. When the handheld receives this message, it gets the data from a server, and passes it to a `DataMap`. This `DataMap` is sent with the following code:

```
NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).await();

for(Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
    PutDataMapRequest dataRequest = PutDataMapRequest.create(mPath);
    dataRequest.getDataMap().putDataMapArrayList("/path", mData);

    PutDataRequest request = dataMapRequest.asPutDataRequest();
    DataApi.DataItemResult result = Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, request).await();

    if(result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "DataMap: " + mData + " sent to: " + node.getDisplayName());
    }
}
```

It seems this code works correctly, as it outputs to logcat: `"DataMap: <mData> sent to: 7f7fbd33"`. Then the <strike>handheld</strike> wearable receives this data in an `AsyncTask` using the following code:

```
NodeApi.GetLocalNodeResult localNode =
    Wearable.NodeApi.getLocalNode(getGoogleApiClient()).await();
Uri dataUri = new Uri.Builder().scheme(PutDataRequest.WEAR_URI_SCHEME)
    .authority(localNode.getNode().getId()).path("/path").build();
Log.d(dataUri.toString());

DataApi.DataItemResult itemResult =
    Wearable.DataApi.getDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, dataUri).await();
Log.d(TAG, itemResult.getStatus() + " dataItem=" + dataItem.getDataItem();

if(itemResult.getStatus().isSuccess() && itemResult.getDataItem() != null) {
    ...
}
```

The path seems to be correct: `wear://7f7fbd33/path`, but the result ends up being: `Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null} dataItem=null`. Why is it giving me a null item?

Comment: I am a bit confused; the second snippet is still running on the handheld? Did you mean to say watch?

Comment: @AliNaddaf Sorry, yes, I meant watch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the watch device, why are you getting the localNode and constructing a dataUri using that? When a DataItem is created, its Uri includes the nodeId of the creator, so if you add a data item on the mobile device, its uri includes the nodeId of the mobile device so when you want to search for those items on a different node, you should use the nodeId of the creator (mobile device in your case) and shouldn't use the local nodeId of the receiver to construct your uri, see the [JavaDoc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataApi#dataitem-uri-format). In many cases, you don't know the id of the creator, so you would use [getDataItems](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataApi.html#getDataItems(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20android.net.Uri))() with partial uri, built from the path only. In addition, it is best to use onDataChanged() callback and then filter the messages based on their path.

Comment: You are saying the partial Uri, as in `wear:/path`? I have tried that, by omitting `.authority()`. Like so: `Uri.Builder().scheme(PutDataRequest.WEAR_URI_SCHEME).path("/path").build()`, but I get a similar result; `Status{statusCode=ERROR, resolution=null} deataItem=null`. Also, `onDataChanged()` only works if the data is actually changed, and I would like to be able to get the data even if it has not been changed.

Comment: the partial uri doesn't work with getDataItem(), you should use getDataItems()

Comment: That worked! I switched my code to `DataItemBuffer results = Wearable.DataApi.getDataItems(mGoogleApiClient).await(); DataMapItem dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(results.get(0));`. Thank you. It is a little rough for now, but at least I have something to work with.

Comment: @Bryan you make a mistake if you don't check if results.get(0) has the right path within its uri